# Order by Route intersection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial

Working on a spatial application that uses way points on a map to plot a route (a-b-c-d-e).

This route is submitted to SQL to find the intersecting polygons along a route.

Is it possible to **Order By** route?

Thus results are shown like:

```
WayPoint   | Polygon
a          | 0xE6100....
a          | 0xE6100....
a          | 0xE6100....
a          | 0xE6100....
b          | 0xE6100....
b          | 0xE6100....
b          | 0xE6100....
c          | 0xE6100....
d          | 0xE6100....
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` route _how_?    It looks like you have them ordered by waypoint at the moment, what do you want instead?  Providing sample starting data and desired outputs increases our ability to help you, and we'd also like your initial query.

Comment: For example if I have a route going from Florida to the west coast of Ireland. My linestring would be: 

    LINESTRING (-81.724189758300781 24.826038360595703, -8.8418722152709961 54.005157470703125) 

I would want to order the result set by point of the route in which they intersect if I was travelling from FL to IRE

Comment: Assuming you know the point at which they intersect, this is pretty easy: order by the intersections' (squared) distance from the starting point.  Unfortunately, I haven't worked with a geo-spatial setup, so I don't completely know what's available...